# Prove that there exist a number $p$ as well as a function $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which $\eta^{1}=p\omega^{1}+dg$.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Let $\eta^{1}$ be a closed 1-form on $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$ and $\omega^{1}$
>   the winding form. Prove that there exist a number $p$ as well as a function
>   $g:\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ for which $$\eta^{1}=p\omega^{1}+dg$$.

My approach: Let $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))$ and the widing form $\omega^{1}=\dfrac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}dy-\dfrac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}dx$, then
$$f^{*}(\omega^{1})=\left(\dfrac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\circ f\right)d(y\circ f)-\left(\dfrac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\circ f\right)d(x\circ f)=d\theta$$

Now I'm stuck, how continuos this?? regards!

Comment: Sorry for out topic. Is there a way to follow a quetion? For example I would like to follow this question and know when someone will eventually answer or comment! Thanks!

Comment: Could you please say more about available tools? Particularly, what conditions are sufficient to show a closed $1$-form is exact? Do you know that: 1. An exact $1$-form in the $(r, \theta)$ plane that is invariant under $2\pi$-translation in $\theta$ "pushes forward" to an exact $1$-form in the punctured plane? 2. A closed $1$-form in a convex/star-shaped/simply-connected region is exact? 3. A closed form is exact if and only if its integral around every closed path vanishes?